# Unable to use org-roam in Emacs on Windows 10

Tags: emacs, windows-10, org-mode

The problem is quite simple :

I want to use org-roam on my Emacs on my Windows 10 laptop, and for a mysterious reason, it just won't work.

What I have done :

1. I have installed org-roam by adding those lines in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file :

```
(use-package org-roam
  :ensure t
  :custom
(org-roam-directory "~/RoamNotes")
  :bind (("C-c n l" . org-roam-buffer-toggle)
         ("C-c n f" . org-roam-node-find)
         ("C-c n i" . org-roam-node-insert)))
```

2. I have `emacsql` and `emacsql-sqlite` installed by adding those lines in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file :

```
(use-package emacsql
      :ensure t)
    (use-package emacsql-sqlite
      :ensure t)
```

3. I have `sqlite3` installed :

```
λ sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.41.2 2023-03-22 11:56:21
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

4. The path to `sqlite3.exe` is in my `PATH` environment variable and in `exec-path` emacs' variable.

What does it do :

When opening a file `~/Documents/RoamNotes/test.org` and hitting `C-c n i` (org-roam-node-insert) or `C-c n f` (org-roam-node-find) to insert or find a node, I get the message `Process emacsql-sqlite not running`

Comment: For a starter, see [Cannot enable org-roam mode - No EmacSQL SQLite binary avaiable](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/56064/28451).

Comment: Hi @Y.E., thanks but I've tried those actually, did not solve my problem.. :/